# How to set an SQL query that a column which contain a full timestamp will equal to a part of the timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

In the db, a column name `punch_in_utc_time` contain a **full** timestamp eg 2018-02-28 09:32:00.

In the SQL query, i'd like to  compare it to a shorter version of timestamp eg 
2018-02-28

Now `punch_in_utc_time` != '2018-02-28'
Is there sth i could do so that in the SQL Query that punch_in_utc_time == '2018-02-28'

my database

[image]

PHPMYADMIN SQL Result[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable
WHERE DATE(punch_in_utc_time)=current_date;
```

For testing:

```
SELECT DATE("2018-02-28 09:32:00")=current_date;
```

See [DEMO on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/17666).

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to do that using Date function, TRUNC timestamp to date then compare with the date field.

```
SELECT DATE("2018-02-28 09:32:00") = "2018-02-28";
```

The above dml will return 1 since the date part is equal.

Comment: please check the capture pic in the edited question, still cant get it.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you wanted:

If you are using earlier version of SQL server use

```
CONVERT
```

(otherwise you might have to use `DATEPART` function instead), do this:
`SELECT CONVERT(punch_in_utc_time)` which will give you date only value.

So in your comparison:

```
SELECT 'TRUE' WHERE Convert(Date, @utc_datetime_x) = '2018-02-28'
```

The above will give you true result.

NOTE: There are NO == in SQL, IF statement could be used with single =, and BEGIN/END act like ():

```
IF Convert(Date, @utc_datetime_x) = '2018-02-28' 
BEGIN
    Select 'True'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    Select 'False'
END
```